# MATLAB-like variable editor in Python

Tags: python, numpy, ipython

Is there a data viewer in Python/IPython like the variable editor in MATLAB?

Comment: Not as far as I know. I just use `who` and `whos` really often.

Answer (score 9):

You should try spiderlib:

http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/

it's a dev environment a la matlab.

Answer (score 0):

No, because python is not an integrated environment, but "only" a programming language. You can use `locals` or `globals` to give the defined variables. You can filter them with something like this:

```
filter(lambda x: not x.startswith("__"), locals())
```

Answer (score 0):

in ipython, `ipipe.igrid()` can be used to view tabular data.

Answer (score 0):

Even Pycharm will be a good option if you are looking for MATLAB like editor.